# Can't seem to properly center widgets

Tags: flutter

I've wrapped these SizedBoxes within a Wrap() widget and have been trying to get them to center properly but haven't been able to do so. Not really sure why the top two widgets are off centered to the left side as seen here:

[Screenshot][1]

They Center perfectly when in landscape mode but whenever the device is in portrait they don't seem to center properly.
Could anyone help with this?

Comment: Please add the code-snippet and the screen-shot so that people can help.

Answer (score 0):

Thank for providing the full code, it helps facilitate the debugging process.

This is what you should do.

1. Remove the padding widgets since it is considered as one of the children to wrap.
2. Use `runSpacing` to space out the wrap children.

follow this [link](https://dartpad.dartlang.org/b6409e10de32b280b8938aa75364fa7b) to see the solution in dartpad

Answer (score 0):

Is there a valid reason you are using a `Wrap`? If not, replace it with a `Column` and remove all of you attributes and it should work. Here is the code I used to get everything centered:

```dart
SingleChildScrollView(
      child: Center(
        child: Column(
            children: [
              SizedBox(
                width: 250,
                height: 200,
                child: RaisedButton(
                  shape: new RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15)),
                  //focusColor: Colors.transparent,
                  highlightColor: Colors.white,
                  //textColor: Colors.deepOrangeAccent,
                  color: Colors.transparent,
                  onPressed: () {},
                  child: Column(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Icon(Icons.local_movies,
                        size: 30,),
                      Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),),
                      Text('Movies',
                        style: GoogleFonts.lobster(fontSize: 30, color: Colors.white),),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.all(20),),
              SizedBox(
                width: 250,
                height: 200,
                child: RaisedButton(
                  shape: new RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15)),
                  color: Colors.transparent,
                  onPressed: () {},
                  child: Column(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Icon(Icons.tv,
                        size: 30,),
                      Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),),
                      Text('Shows',
                        style: GoogleFonts.lobster(fontSize: 30, color: Colors.white),),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.all(20),),
              SizedBox(
                width: 250,
                height: 200,
                child: RaisedButton(
                  shape: new RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15)),
                  color: Colors.transparent,
                  onPressed: () {},
                  child: Column(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Icon(Icons.live_tv,
                        size: 30,),
                      Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),),
                      Text('Live TV',
                        style: GoogleFonts.lobster(fontSize: 30, color: Colors.white),),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ]
        ),
      ),
    );
```

Hope it helps :) if so please up vote and accept as answer.

Comment: Your code don't work as expected on landscape orientation

Answer (score 0):

Instead of add paddings between your widgets, you may remove them and use Container with paddings instead of SizedBox widgets like this

```
         Container(
            width: 250,
            height: 200,
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(20),
```

To help you on designing your UI, you can activate the debug painting and see all elements composing your UI